# Ubuntu not booting properly at all

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, kernel, 23.04

Today i tried booting my Ubuntu, but it seems like its not able to finish the boot process properly. In GRUB, when i select my kernel version it starts booting as usual but after a few seconds it shows something like these:

[image: this]

[image: this]

Adding `nouveai.modeset=0` or `nouveau.nomodeset` to my kernel parameters didn't work, same outcome. If I try to access recovery mode, there's not much I can do there. `clean` doesn't find any packages to remove, `dpkg` drops a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DistUpgrade'` (something from python) and `fsck` just drops

```
/lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu: line 80: /etc/default/rcS: No such file or directory
fsck from util-linux 2.38.1
/dev/sda2 is mounted
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting
```

If I try to resume the boot from there, there's just a black screen and a blinking dash.

The boot device is still the right one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it!

1. Go into recovery mode
2. Open root shell prompt
3. type `sudo apt purge gdm gdm3`
4. resume to normal boot
5. login
6. type `sudo apt install gdm3 ubuntu-desktop` and `systemctl restart gdm`
7. done